# Question on using "the" with "future"

Tags: articles

```
1. ...most intriguing question about the future of wireless communications...


2. What's your view about future of wireless?
```

Is it possible to remove *the* from the first sentence or add *the* to the second?

Comment: Ditto with _past_. Executive summary: ***Article usage in English is almost entirely idiomatic.***

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I don't think I've ever seen 'future' used as a noun without an article, so your second example looks very strange indeed.

I'd only omit the article if using 'future' as an adjective, e.g.: "...most intriguing question about future wireless communications" and "What's your view about the future of wireless?"